# Understanding an AJAX basic function for cascading dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have successfully edited a script to define a 2-level nested dropdown lists, that uses a MySQL table, some PHP and a JavaScript function.

Here it is the Javascript...since I am at the very beginning of the learning curve, would like to take advantage of your help to better understand how the function works and how to modify it (if needed at all):

```
function reload(form)
{
    var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value;
    self.location='dropdowns.php?cat=' + val ;
}
function disableselect()
{
    <?Php
    // code to disable second dropdown when no selection from first dropdown has been made yet
    if(isset($cat) and strlen($cat) > 0){
    echo "document.Demographics.subcat.disabled = false;";}
    else{echo "document.Demographics.subcat.disabled = true;";}
    ?>
}
```

Thank you very much for your patience.

P.S: if this question is inappropriate here, please go ahead and close the discussion

Comment: I don't see any Ajax code in this question. What is your question?

Comment: I am sorry...I meant JavaScript, my apologies